# How to use the Executable (defined as Capability in Bamboo) in the plugin code

Tags: bamboo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

From the sample code on Atlassian site

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/executing-external-processes-using-processservice/

```
ExternalProcess process = ProcessService.createExternalProcess(taskContext, new ExternalProcessBuilder().*command*(Arrays.asList("**/bin/ls**")). workingDirectory(fileWorkingDir));
```

What Bamboo API should I use to fetch "**/home/kshi/.local/bin/robot**" and pass it to *command*(). Getting the values from TaskConfiguration configuration map, or TaskDefinition did not help.

I do have the below tag in my atlassian-plugin.xml

```
< executable key="**robot**" nameKey="RobotFrameworkTest.robotExecutable"/ >
```

RobotFrameworkTest.robotExecutable points to **"robot"**

[image]

I want to make use of the Executable defined in bamboo. (/home/kshi/.local/bin/root)

From the logs of the plan I can see that Bamboo is referring to the robot command as **bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.robot**, wondering if I have to use it in the same way in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a relevant link on Atlassian website hinting ways to use an
executable.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-access-build-variables-from-a-bamboo-task/qaq-p/572570

```
@ComponentImport private final ProcessService processService;
@ComponentImport private final CapabilityContext capabilityContext;

public RobotTestTaskType(final ProcessService processService, final CapabilityContext capabilityContext)

{ this.processService = processService; this.capabilityContext = capabilityContext; }
String robotExecutable = capabilityContext.getCapabilityValue("system.builder.command.robot");
```

Comment: If this is the answer, you should accept it by clicking on the tick to mark the question complete.